# How can I add a shortcut on my desktop to a document in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, document-management

I would like to have a shortcut on my desktop to an Excel document in Google Docs.

How can I create a shortcut (icon) like this? I use Google Chrome as web browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a solution here;

http://www.ampercent.com/create-desktop-shortcuts-of-google-docs-documents/6710/

> 1. Open the document or spreadsheet in your Google docs account and copy the full URL of the document.
> 2. Create a new desktop shortcut and type the URL of he document in the shortcuts location.
> 3. All done, now you have a new shortcut in your desktop – double clicking which will launch the Google document in a new browser tab or window. Now associate specific icon files with these shortcuts so that you can identify them at a glance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Google Drive now lets you "Share" your documents. You can use this to copy the direct URL to your file.

1. Right-click on the document you want to point to and select Share.
2. Copy the URL provided
3. Right-click on your desktop and select 'New' > 'Shortcut' and paste in the copied URL.

[image: Share file]

[image: Copy URL]

[image: Save as shortcut]

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way to create an shortcut to desktop from a webpage is dragging browser address directly to desktop.

[image: Click and drag with left mouse button tiny sheet next in address to desktop and release mouse button.]

Click and drag with left mouse button tiny sheet next in address to desktop and release mouse button.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using Google Chrome as a browser for this (I do not know if it'll work with IE, Firefox, or any other). To create a shortcut for any file in your Drive to your desktop is to simply open the file, then click on the button at the top right of the page (1), and scroll down to "More Tools" (2). You'll see the option "Create Application Shortcuts" (3), and that's all she wrote!

[image: annotated screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) app (now Backup and Sync) installed, right-click the file and choose "Send To -> Desktop (create shortcut).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to options and create the shortcut.

Screenshot in spanish:

[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot in english:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Options where? It's not clear how you're doing this.

Comment: Could you also please show the menu options in English? It will be difficult for non Spanish speakers to understand this.